# Como navegar entre páginas usando botões com ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic, ionic2

Estou tentando entender como funciona as navegações entre as páginas com `ionic2`. Eu quero que ao clicar no botão abaixo ele me redirecionar a `HomePage`, como posso fazer isso?

Botão no menu.html

```
<button ion-button color="light">Button</button>
```

Meu .ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-menu',
  templateUrl: 'menu.html',  

})
export class MenuPage { 

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public alertCtrl: AlertController) {
  }

  showAlert() {
    const alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'New Friend!',
      subTitle: 'teste',
      buttons: ['OK']
    });
    alert.present();
  }

  openSobre(){
    this.navCtrl.push(HomePage, {}, {animate: true} );    
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad MenuPage');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos supor que você quer ir da HomePage para a SobrePage clicando em um botão que está na HomePage.

Dentro da HomePage.ts importe o `NavController` e o componente `SobrePage`. Crie uma função `openSobre()`, que será chamado ao clicar o botão.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import { SobrePage } from "../sobre/sobre";

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) { }  

  openSobre(){
    this.navCtrl.push(SobrePage, {}, {animate: true} );    
  }
}
```

No seu botão, chame a função `openSobre()`.

```
<button ion-button (click)="openSobre()" color="light">Button</button>
```

Outros detalhes podem ser encontrados na [documentação](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/)

Comment: eu tenho meu MenuPage que ta como root e quero ir pra HomePage, em qual .ts eu coloco?

Comment: O seu menu page é uma pagina ou menu lateral?

Comment: uma pagina que coloquei como sendo a root page

Comment: Entendi. Então através dela que você vai chamar a página HomePage.

Comment: meu component ja tem @Component({  selector: 'page-home',  templateUrl: home.html'}) 
é so adicionar entao selector: 'page-home',  templateUrl: 'home.html nele?

Comment: Edita a sua pergunta colocando como está o seu MenuPage.ts

Comment: adicionei, da uma olhada

Comment: Você ja tem o componente HomePage criado com os arquivos .ts e .html?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81847/discussion-between-hunter-xhunter-and-jraspante).